# The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Security.NegotiationTokenAuthenticator`1'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, wcf-data-services

WCF service hosted with named pipe started to throw some weird errors, is not able to initialize and it throwing weird error.

I recently upgraded to VS2015 Ultimate, and I changed the namespace of the project. I am sure change of namespace is causing the problem.

Config looks straightforward.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<netNamedPipeBinding>
<binding name="netNamedPipeBinding" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
</binding>
</netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
<client/>
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="Company.Service1Behavior"  name="Company.DBSync">
<endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexNamedPipeBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange"  kind="mexEndpoint" />
<endpoint binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="netNamedPipeBinding"  name="netPipeSync"  contract="Company.IDBSyncService" />
<host>
<baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Project/Sync/" />
</baseAddresses>
</host>
</service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="Company.Service1Behavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityBindingElement
Error: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Security.NegotiationTokenAuthenticator`1' threw an exception.**

> Error Stack:
>       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
>       Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityBindingElement
>       Error: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Security.NegotiationTokenAuthenticator`1' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Security.NegotiationTokenAuthenticator`1' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.DXD' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

```
at System.ServiceModel.TrustDec2005Dictionary.PopulateDec2005DictionaryStrings()
       at System.ServiceModel.DXD..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityTokenSerializer..ctor(SecurityVersion securityVersion, TrustVersion trustVersion, SecureConversationVersion secureConversationVersion, Boolean emitBspRequiredAttributes, SamlSerializer samlSerializer, SecurityStateEncoder securityStateEncoder, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes, Int32 maximumKeyDerivationOffset, Int32 maximumKeyDerivationLabelLength, Int32 maximumKeyDerivationNonceLength)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityTokenSerializer.get_DefaultInstance()
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityStandardsManager..ctor()
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityStandardsManager.get_DefaultInstance()
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.NegotiationTokenAuthenticator`1..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.LocalServiceSecuritySettings..ctor()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement..ctor()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement..ctor()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.ExportPolicyForTransportTokenAssertionProviders(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext context)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.WSMexImpl.GatherMetadata(String dialect, String identifier)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.WSMexImpl.Get(Message request)
       at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I never setup this to be secure since this only runs on a local machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The key part of the error is `Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program`, that's kinda screwy. Can you test this on another machine?

Comment: Yeah tried on another machine, doesn't help. Never saw this error before and I don't know what it translates to, I assume it could be only limited to namedpipes, I could try wshttp and rule out machine dependence.

Comment: I slept on it after having wasted 10 hours trying to solve the problem, and like one of those bugs, it went away on its own. Maybe not on its own per se, but after I have repaired VS2015 and .NET Framework, I assume it caused problems on another machine, because it was another copy of the VM, so it had the same state.